# How is it possible to make a procedural snakeskin texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

I've seen some posts like this [one](https://twitter.com/simonthommes/status/1086709629701287937) showing snakeskin procedural textures.

How is this possible? From what I've gleamed on reddit, a voronoi texture is used here? How would you morph that texture into a directional "scale" looking geometry?

Comment: Good question. Start by looking at his nodes: https://gumroad.com/l/sneks That particular artist (Simon Thommes) gives pretty much everything he releases away for free. Lots of good shaders to study on his gumroad.